# How to litterbox train an adult dog, that has not be previously housebroken?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, toilet-training

I would like to train my small adult dog to use a litter box (or puppy pads).  Currently he is not housebroken and messes all over the house.

I am not sure if I should use a litterbox (*like for a cat*) or a puppy pads in the place I want him to go to the toilet.  Please indicate pros and cons of each in your answer.

I don't have any really experience with housebreaking a dog, so would like a detailed answer on; How to litterbox train an adult dog, that has not be previously housebroken?